# I'm trying to make an A-Z book for children

Tags: creative-writing

I'm trying to make an A-Z book for children to get them interested in science. Each letter will be a futuristic technology/invention/concept and will give an easy to read explanation. I need creative fresh ideas. I don't want to just say A for Antimatter Rocket. I would like an A-Z of good ideas. Thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Stack Exchange is not like other sites. We are not an online workshop or a discussion board. We are a Q&A site. We require clear, answerable questions which are likely to help others in the future. This is a "what to write" question, which is off-topic for us because it is unlikely to help anyone else. Please take our tour and see our help center  https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to see what kinds of questions we answer here.